# Upload to SoftLayer Object Storage from FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

Has anyone tried to integrate FineUploader with SoftLayer's Object Storage?

http://www.softlayer.com/cloudlayer/storage

It is built on OpenStack's Swift and is similar to S3 in concept.  I think that FineUploader would need to be able to work with their REST API calls for it to work, but maybe there is a DIY way to do it.

I do not want to put my own server in between as for my needs, I would then not need the Object Storage service.  Goal would be to not run a server for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the short answer is no. We are going to add support for Rackspace's Cloud Files (based on OpenStack's Swift, as well) within the next 2 releases. I'd appreciate if you could chime in on the issue tracker and add your support: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1025 -- note that issue is regarding Rackspace, but since they are both using Swift it may be easy to support both Rackspace and Softlayer as well as any other cloud services using Swift.

Comment: Thanks, I had opened an issue so I updated it to reference this one.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! This is now the 3rd case we've in the past few weeks requesting support for OpenStack's Object Storage so I could see it becoming an implemented feature here very soon.

Comment: @MarkFeltner this is since 2013 ! we are 2016 now, fineuploader still doesn't support softlayer?!!

Answer (score 0):

Softlayer is now bluemix and is its object storage is S3 capable. 
Instruction for fineUploader are here ( depending on what you want to do) :

http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server-s3.html

You will need to replace access_id and secret_access_key by your softlayer/bluemix one.

Endpoints are available once you create your object storage account, it will be something like this :

https://s3-api.dal-us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/

Details are here of the API are here : 
https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-operations.html